# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group when run in iphone 5 Device

Tags: ios, xcode8, iphone-5

Whenever I run my application in `iPhone 5 device model:A1429` I get the following error:

[image]

I am unable to run the application in iPhone 5 model through. While the app runs fine through simulator and `iphone 6s,6s+ device`. Whereas, I am able to run other projects in my iphone 5 device.

Please help me, why I am not able to run my application in `iphone 5 Device`?

**Note:**
Iphone5 iOS version: 10.3.2(14F89)
Xcode version: 8.3.2 (8E2002)

**Error Message:**

> Ld
>   /Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app/myApp
>   normal armv7 cd "/Users/mydrive/Desktop/myApp 2" export
>   IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0 export
>   PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/mydrive/Desktop/myApp\ 2/myApp -F/Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -filelist /Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myApp.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myApp_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myApp.swiftmodule
>   -framework Security /Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libsqlcipher.a
>   -lsqlite3.0 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myApp_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/mydrive/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-eqvhrwwgwngmksguwakvgjbdeygf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app/myApp

Comment: show the full error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i used `SqlCipher project` in my application. setting `Enable Bitcode=No`. Remove the error and my application is successfully run on `iPhone 5 device`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This problem has different solutions , one of them is to set **Enable Bitcode** to **No** . 
[image]( By the way , this may not the solution for you but there is a good possibility . Just try )

Comment: r u  using any pod file ? I mean any third party frameworks

Comment: This problem is a ghost like problem . Clearing Cache , Restarting Xcode , Simulator and MAC ,Ensuring proper linking of Frameworks  or , Sometimes just doing nothing can solve this problem .

Comment: kindly see the Error message. also i dont use any pod file in my application

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode Then Launch it DO

Product > Clean or Shift + Command + K

then Run Your Project

Hope it works